# Problem with basic average speed formula in java

Tags: java

I am trying to build a very simple average speed formula one that takes the input of miles and hours and gives the average speed per hour. Bear with me because I literally started learning Java yesterday. I am not trying to do decimals or anything I just want to get a straight result from the formula.

```
public class AverageSpeed {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please enter the distance you travelled in miles: ");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String Miles = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter the time in hours, it has taken to travel this distance. ");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String Hours = sc.nextInt();


        int distance = Integer.parseInt(Miles);

        int time = Integer.parseInt(Hours);

        int averagespeed = distance / time;

        System.out.println("You were travelling an average speed " + averagespeed + " miles per hours.");

    }
}
```

I'm getting the error message: `duplicate local variable sc`. I know I'm using the scanner completely wrong. I have no idea how to fix the scanner part and  get the formula working. And I don't have enough experience to fix or completely understand the commands yet.

Comment: You are missing some closing `}`. fix the code

Comment: `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); ` is declared twice in your code, and a variable can't be re-declared. An alternative might be to name the second scanner something different (like `sc2`) or re-use the first scanner by replacing the above code with `sc = new Scanner(System.in); `.

Comment: Also you are trying to assign an int to a String variable here - `String Hours = sc.nextInt();`

Comment: please use a an IDE like eclipse which will help you to solve most of the syntactical issues :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you have declared **sc** twice in line 4 and 7. You need not to instantiate Scanner multiple times the same instance will work for multiple inputs. Also, on line 8
`String Hours = sc.nextInt();`
it is incorrect you're storing an int value in String type, which is quite wrong.
Below code will fulfill the requirements,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AverageSpeed {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please enter the distance you travelled in miles: ");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String miles = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter the time in hours, it has taken to travel this distance. ");

        String hours = sc.nextLine();

        int distance = Integer.parseInt(miles);

        int time = Integer.parseInt(hours);

        int averagespeed = distance / time;

        System.out.println("You were travelling an average speed " + averagespeed + " miles per hours.");

    }
}
```

Also, just a suggestion variable names should start with lowercase thats a java convention.

Answer (score 0):

You have currently defined `sc`, so you have to change it's value, not create the new with the same name:

```java
sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

But, you don't need to do that. Just create one scanner in `sc` variable.

If you want to get more precise result, consider changing the type of `averagespeed` to [`float`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) or [`double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html).